# Sqlalchemy declarative, which methods can I override?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have some existing Python objects that I’m now mapping with sqlalchemy.

The Base class created with declarative base appears to have many protocol __ methods like **eq** etc.  I need to override hash and possibly others.  I’m concerned that I may break some SA magic.

How do I figure out what’s safe or not?

Do people typically only use composition in these situations?  (In my case I will need to create a bunch of @properties in that case)